# Javascript,Highcharts : Avoiding parallel function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am developing a dashboard, where there  are `5 buttons`, and on click of each button, corresponding chart is displayed in the same `div`.

The structure of my code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
       function requestData() {
          $.ajax({
             url : ....,
             success : function(){
                          .....
                          //Real Time Plotting of Data
                          chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
                          setTimeout(requestData, 2000);
                       }
            });
         }
          chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                  chart: {
                           renderTo: 'chart',
                           defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
                          },
                          ....                              
                          ....
           });
    });

});
```

The Problem : On every click of the button, a parallel requestData() starts, multiple parallel threads run at the same time. This leads in random `addPoint` and increase in memory consumed.

Also, when checked with `Highcharts.Chart` in the console, after every click, a `undefined` objects adds up.

How do I restructure the code for optimum performance ?

Comment: On success of requestData (in ajax calll) you are again calling requestData or I am not understanding your code?

Comment: This code adds a point every 2 seconds, something like a realtime plot. Hence, after adding a point, I am recalling the ajax, so that new values are fetched.

Comment: Where is the performance issue on server (db/web server/network) or on client (browser)?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code below, your high chart implement can be like this

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Basically, you do not need to make your arrangement to live plotting, high chart has this option UPDATE
Refer live fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/3u0ng35s/

Replace below data option to your ajax call

```
 data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }
```